# How to using pandas to cell merge

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to combine the cells as follows.

Before:

```
|   | test1 | test2 | test3 |
| -:|:----- |:----- | -----:|
| 0 | value | value | value |
| 1 | test4 | test5 |
| 2 | value | value |
| 3 | test6 | test7 | test8 |
| 4 | value | value | value |
| 5 | test9 | test0 |
| 6 | value | value |
```

After:

```
|   | test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 | test5 | test6 | test7 | test8 | test9 | test0 |
| -:|:----- |:----- | ----- |:----- |:----- |:----- |:----- |:----- |:----- | -----:|
| 0 | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value | value |
```

I want to change the cells using the Python code with the help of pandas. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you can do.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test1 ':['15','test4','79', 'test6', '34', 'test9', '323'],
                   'test2 ':['78','test5','45', 'test7', '4', 'test10', '34'],
                   'test3 ':['8','','', 'test8', '56', '', '']})
print("Original Dataframe")
print(df)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
col_names = []
col_names = df.iloc[1::2, :].to_numpy('str').tolist()
row_values = df.iloc[2::2, :].to_numpy('str').tolist()
col_names = [j for sub in col_names for j in sub if j!= '']
row_values = [j for sub in row_values for j in sub if j!= '']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([row_values], columns= col_names)
print("Dataframe 1")
print(df1)

df2 = df.iloc[[0, ]]
print("Dataframe 2")
print(df2)

df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)
print("Dataframe Result")
print(df3)
```

The `df1` contains all the data except for the first one. The `df2` contains only original columns and first row. Finally, you concatenate `df1 and df2` to form `df3`.

This gives you an output as:

```
Original Dataframe
  test1   test2  test3 
0     15      78      8
1  test4   test5       
2     79      45       
3  test6   test7  test8
4     34       4     56
5  test9  test10       
6    323      34       
Dataframe 1
  test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10
0    79    45    34     4    56   323     34
Dataframe 2
  test1  test2  test3 
0     15     78      8
Dataframe Result
  test1  test2  test3  test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10
0     15     78      8    79    45    34     4    56   323     34
```

Comment: Thanks I Will try it

Answer (score 2):

Slice from row 1 and pre-process it with `melt` to series `s`. Slice even rows of `s` for columns and odd rows for values and construct a new dataframe from these columns and values. Finally, join to row 0 of original df

```
Sample df:
    test1   test2   test3
0  value1  value2  value3
1   test4   test5     NaN
2  value4  value5     NaN
3   test6   test7   test8
4  value6  value7  value8
5   test9   test0     NaN
6  value9  value0     NaN

s = df.iloc[1:].melt().dropna()['value']
cols = s[0::2].tolist()
vals = s[1::2].tolist()
df_final = df.iloc[[0]].join(pd.DataFrame([vals], columns=cols)).sort_index(1)

Out[140]:
    test0   test1   test2   test3   test4   test5   test6   test7   test8  \
0  value0  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  value6  value7  value8

    test9
0  value9
```

Comment: Thanks I Will try it